# Accessing element in JSON array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, api

I am making a API in Javascript to get some details.

Calling the following: `APICall.Employee.getAll();`
returns:

```
[{
    "id": 123456,
    "first_name": "Joe ",
    "last_name": "Soap",
    "email": "",
    "image_url": "http",
    "updated_on": "2017-03-06 12:09:47"
}, {
    "id": 000123,
    "first_name": "Mary",
    "last_name": "Soap",
    "email": "",
    "image_url": "http",
    "updated_on": "2017-03-07 06:31:25"
}]
```

I am trying to access each employees ID. When I test the call, I get the error: "*ReferenceError: employees is not defined*"

```
var json = APICall.Employee.getAll();
print("Employees: " + json); // Returns [object Array]...[object Array]
for (i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    print("ID: " + employees.id); // ReferenceError: employees is not defined
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? How do I access the employee ID?

Comment: [There's nothing JSON related in the question](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: So, where is "employees" defined? You're looping based on json.length, but trying to print from a variable called "employees"? That's why its telling you employees is not defined. Try `json.employees.id`

Comment: @mstorkson I think that `APICall.Employee.getAll();` is returning an array of objects with the same shape as the referenced example.

Comment: Tried that as well but get error: "Cannot read property 'first_name' of undefined"

Comment: @heyred do print(JSON.stringify(json, null, 2)) and add the output to your question. Let's at least be sure your API call is returning what you think it is

Comment: @Quentin: Sure looks like a valid JSON structure up at the top. I don't see any indication that it's embedded in a JS program.

Comment: @mstorkson I have now updated the output of JSON.stringify to the question.

Comment: So then `getAll()` is parsing the JSON, and returning the `employees` array. So iterate that just like any other array. In other words, `json` is the array, so `json[i]` gets the current item in the loop. If `getAll()` is your API, it would've been better if you had shown the actual code that is relevant to the question.

Comment: @squint Im not sure what else to show as that is all the code there is in the script

Comment: Is `getAll()` your function? We were having to guess at what it was returning. If it's your code, then you're the only one who knows what that would be. So again, it appears to be returning the `employees`, array instead of the entire structure, so the `json` variable points to that Array, so `json[i]` in the loop is the solution to accessing each object, so `json[i].id` gives you the ID
.

Answer (score 2):

So first of all, you're using the length of json, which doesn't exist. And secondly, you're never using the index i. Here is a fixed version.

```
var json = APICall.Employee.getAll();
print("Employees: " + json); // Returns [object Array]...[object Array]
for (i = 0; i < json.employees.length; i++) {
    print("ID: " + json.employees[i].id); // ReferenceError: employees is not defined
}
```

You'll notice that I look for the length of the employees array now. And I also index into that array inside the loop by doing json.employees[i]

Update: to go with your new code:

```
var json = APICall.Employee.getAll();
for (i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    print("ID: " + json[i].id);
}
```

Comment: I think that `APICall.Employee.getAll();` is returning an array of objects with the same shape as the referenced example.

Comment: @JDB what makes you assume that? The object in the example does contain a list of employees and so is an appropriate return type for GetAll(). It also explains his error.

Comment: When I try the answer here I get the error: "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Comment: I assume that because the OP wasn't getting an error when reading json.length. If that property was undefined, then the code would never make it into the for loop and would never execute the code which is supposedly throwing the error.

Answer (score 2):

```
var json = APICall.Employee.getAll();
print("Employees: " + json); // Returns [object Array]...[object Array]
for (i = 0; i < json.employees.length; i++) {
    print("ID: " + json.employees[i].id); // ReferenceError: employees is not defined
}
```

Comment: I think that `APICall.Employee.getAll();` is returning an array of objects with the same shape as the referenced example.

Comment: then change your json structure first then ask your question

Comment: It's not my question. But yes... I agree... it's better to ask a good question so that people don't waste their time on answering the wrong question.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't referencing the JSON key "employees" and the for loop isn't doing anything.

You'd need to do:

```
var employees = json.employees;
```

Then iterate over that object:

```
for (var i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
    print("ID: " + employees[i].id);
};
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I think that `APICall.Employee.getAll();` is returning an array of objects with the same shape as the referenced example.

Comment: The question says "The JSON Array that is returned to me looks exactly as per below". I figured status, tag, employee etc were all keys of the returned JSON